# Better pipeline utilization causes lower performance in GPUs

Tags: performance, opencl, gpu, flops

I'm developing a simple OpenCL kernel, which is only doing computation with no memory access at all. Here is the kind of kernel we are executing on the GPU:

```
__kernel void WGS512MAPI8LLXOPS64(const __global float *GIn, __global float *GOut, const int M, const int N, const int P) {
         const int XGL = get_global_id(0);
         const int XGRid = get_group_id(0);
         const int XGRnum = get_num_groups(0);
         const int XLSize = get_local_size(0);
         const int XLid = get_local_id(0);
         // Just a private variable
         float temp1 = 1.0;
         float temp2 = 1.0;
         float temp3 = 1.0;
         float temp4 = 1.0;
         float tempOut;
         float MF = (float) M;
         float NF = (float) N;
         float PF = (float) P;


         // Start of a new level of for loop
         long baseIndex1 = XGRid*XLSize*8+XLid;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         ...
         temp1 += temp1 * MF;
         tempOut = temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4;
         GOut[XGRid*XLSize*8+XLid] = tempOut;
}
```

The total number of "FMA operations" is about 1024. Based on the kernel, every instruction require the previous instruction to be finished first, due to existence of data dependency. I have tried to optimize execution of above kernel, but utilizing more temp variables to increase the gap between data dependent operations like below:

```
__kernel void WGS512MAPI8LLXOPS64(const __global float *GIn, __global float *GOut, const int M, const int N, const int P) {
         const int XGL = get_global_id(0);
         const int XGRid = get_group_id(0);
         const int XGRnum = get_num_groups(0);
         const int XLSize = get_local_size(0);
         const int XLid = get_local_id(0);
         // Just a private variable
         float temp1 = 1.0;
         float temp2 = 1.0;
         float temp3 = 1.0;
         float temp4 = 1.0;
         float tempOut;
         float MF = (float) M;
         float NF = (float) N;
         float PF = (float) P; 

         // Start of a new level of for loop
         long baseIndex1 = XGRid*XLSize*8+XLid;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         ...
         temp1 += temp1 * MF; temp2 += temp2 * NF;
         tempOut = temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4;
         GOut[XGRid*XLSize*8+XLid] = tempOut;
}
```

Executing and calculating the total the total GFLOPs of both kernel (while the total number of operations for both are the same), the first kernel gives around 1186.17 GFLOPs and the second kernel gives around 600.58 GFLOPS, which is completely against my first assumption. Since I have rolled out memory access completely, I cannot come up with another explanation for this numbers.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows what's going on on the device level while these kernels are being executed.

Comment: Do you have any previous experience with performance measurement? I am just asking, because if you do, you'll know its very tricky ;-)

Comment: This is basically what I do. I compute the total number of floating point operations being calculated, based on how many work item i deploy and how many operations being done by each work item. Then I also calculate how long it takes for the kernel to be executed. That way I can calculate the flops.

Comment: Which hardware is that?

Comment: I'm deploying the code onto Tesla K40M.

Comment: Could it be the core feeding bottleneck? I've read in forums that that series can barely feed all cores because of not enough data lanes. Can you try same with using define macros or constants instead of register variables please? (`float MF = (float) M;` there M instead of MF). Having one operand (of a+=b*c) come as constant may increase bandwidth per calculation. Maybe its just compiler/driver's crippled state because of some "beta" launch? Also you are doing additions for completely different sums without making them work for same total sum. Isn't temp1 and temp2 supposed to be for same sum

Comment: I basically was suing M instead of MF before (M is defined as const in the kernel input variables), but the result was the same (First kernel gets better performance than second kernel). Using M reduces performance since everytime it should be converted into float and then be used. Regarding the different sums for temp1 and temp2, I haven't completely got your point. Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to see if using second kernel gives higher opportunity for the scheduler to utilize the core on GPU much more efficiently. So at least I should observer the same performance, which is not the case. Seems like the second kernel causes more stalls than the first kernel, for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: I meant that both temps work for same summation, to utilize pipeline more for it. Also how do you know if there are conversions from double to float at each step? Did you look at produced binary/il code? Do you have a kernel analyzer? Putting `f` prefix to constant literals doesn't solve the conversion? How many registers are used per kernel?

Comment: Yes I took a look at PTX code and see for each line of computation, one conversion is going to happen. This was also weird to me, cause I thought compiler will take care of it, by doing conversion only once.